# Android AndEngine score += 1 error increases a lot

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am creating sprites that get saved into a list called `listSprites` each sprite that touches a line (`line3`) that I made gets `detached` from the screen. What I want is when It gets detached (collides with line3) the score increases only 1, but now it increases a lot like it reacher 10,218 in 1 minute, once a sprite collides with the line it detaches and the score starts increasing without stopping even though no sprite is coliiding with it.

```
                /* The actual collision-checking. */
                mScene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void reset() { }

                @Override
                public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {

                    } for(Sprite s: listSprites){
                        if (s.collidesWith(line3)){
                                mScore += 1;
                                mScene.detachChild(s);
                                mText.setText(" "+mScore+"");

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

                }
```

Comment: Are you also removing the sprite from `listSprites`? I don't know how andengine "detaches" sprites, but it looks like a detached sprite can still collide.

Comment: if I do listSprite.remove(s) much errors occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `collidesWith()` doesn't care whether the child is attached or not. If that's the case, and you don't want to remove the sprite from `listSprites`, you need to check each sprite in the list to see if it's attached in addition to the collision check.

I haven't used andengine much, but from looking at the source and examples, it looks like you could just do something as simple as changing:

```
if (s.collidesWith(line3)){
```

to:

```
if (s.hasParent() && s.collidesWith(line3)){
```

`hasParent()` should return false if the sprite is not attached to anything, so check for that.

This assumes that you're not attaching the sprites to a different scene in the meantime.

Comment: I get The method getChildIndex(Sprite) is undefined for the type Scene. thanks for answering

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at outdated source files, and I guess they removed it. You should be able to use `s.hasParent()` or check the `getChildByMatcher()` function in the newer sources.